# How to SetValues to a range with a different dimension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to prepare an empty sheet to be the size of a SetValues.

**Details**

I'm trying to use [this nice routine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66142539/4313324) from [clueless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15185344/clueless) to make a values-only copy of a google sheet file including all tabs.  (Ultimately I'll run it on a schedule and download it to microsoft cloud drive so I can access live from Power BI).  Clueless uses hard-coded parameters TL and BR to represent the Top Left and Bottom Right of the ranges.  Clueless starts by deleting any tab with a matching name in the destination sheet, thus starting with a new tab.

Unfortunately, my source sheet tabs' ranges are not all consistent.  Some larger than TL BL and some smaller.  Therefore I get either "...out of bounds..." errors or "The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. " if I increase or decrease the TL and BL globals.

How to I solve this?  Is there maybe a way to prepare the destination sheet, before SetValues, by making it's size match the source sheet GetDataRange size before SetValues is executed?

Thanks!

```
    function update_view(dup_id="<spreadsheet_id>", TL="A1", BR="BE900") {
    // Open current Sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    // Supply a duplicate google doc ID. This document will be exported to excel
    var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dup_id)
    // UI element for notifying in the google sheets
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    //Copy each sheet one by one
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
        src_sheet = sheets[i];
        sheet_name = src_sheet.getName();
        Logger.log(sheet_name);
        // If same sheet exists in the destination delete it and create an empty one
        dst_sheet = ds.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
        if (dst_sheet != null) {
            ds.deleteSheet(dst_sheet)
        }
        dst_sheet = ds.insertSheet(sheet_name);
        //set column width correctly
        for(j=1; j<=src_sheet.getLastColumn(); j++){
            dst_sheet.setColumnWidth(j, src_sheet.getColumnWidth(j))
        }
        src_range = src_sheet.getRange(TL + ":" + BR);
        dst_range = dst_sheet.getRange(TL + ":" + BR);
        //Note: DisplayValues is set as Values, formulas are removed in dup sheet
        dst_range.setValues(src_range.getDisplayValues());
        //Nice to haves for formatting
        dst_range.setFontColors(src_range.getFontColors());
        dst_range.setFontStyles(src_range.getFontStyles());
        dst_range.setBackgrounds(src_range.getBackgrounds());
        dst_range.setHorizontalAlignments(src_range.getHorizontalAlignments());
        dst_range.setVerticalAlignments(src_range.getVerticalAlignments());
        dst_range.setWraps(src_range.getWraps());

        dst_contents_range = dst_sheet.getDataRange();
        dst_contents_range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
    }
    //Completed copy, Now open the dup document and export.
    ui.alert("Backup Complete, Please open " + dup_id + " sheet to view contents.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using A1 notation to get the range you might use `getDataRange()` to grab the data range (the all the rows and columns having at least one cell with a value), then might use `getNumRows()`, `getNumColumns()` among other methods or use `Array.prototype.length()` to get the range dimensions and grab a range of the same size from the destination sheet.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange

Related

- [Getting "Those rows are out of bounds" error in Google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31647891/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Ruben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%C3%A9n).  That was helpful.  using getNumRows() and getNumColumns() did it.
For others here is the complete function.  I also changed the name and replaced my file id with

```
function MakeCopyAsValues(dup_id="<google file id>") {
// Open current Sheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
// Supply a duplicate google doc ID.
var ds = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dup_id)
// UI element for notifying in the google sheets
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
//Copy each sheet one by one
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    src_sheet = sheets[i];
    sheet_name = src_sheet.getName();
    // Logger.log(sheet_name);  // this was helpful for debugging.
    // If same sheet exists in the destination delete it and create an empty one
    dst_sheet = ds.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
    if (dst_sheet != null) {
        ds.deleteSheet(dst_sheet)
    }
    dst_sheet = ds.insertSheet(sheet_name);

    src_range = src_sheet.getDataRange();  //Get the source's range that has data.
    dst_range = dst_sheet.getRange(1,1,src_range.getNumRows(), src_range.getNumColumns());

    //Note: DisplayValues is set as Values, formulas are removed in dup sheet
    dst_range.setValues(src_range.getDisplayValues());
    
    //set column widths correctly.  Moving this after the range setting prevents some errors.
    for(j=1; j<=src_sheet.getLastColumn(); j++){
        dst_sheet.setColumnWidth(j, src_sheet.getColumnWidth(j))
    }
    //Other Nice to haves for formatting
    dst_range.setFontColors(src_range.getFontColors());
    dst_range.setFontStyles(src_range.getFontStyles());
    dst_range.setBackgrounds(src_range.getBackgrounds());
    dst_range.setHorizontalAlignments(src_range.getHorizontalAlignments());
    dst_range.setVerticalAlignments(src_range.getVerticalAlignments());
    dst_range.setWraps(src_range.getWraps());

    dst_contents_range = dst_sheet.getDataRange();
    dst_contents_range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
}
ui.alert("Backup Complete, Please open " + dup_id + " sheet to view contents.")
```

}